# How to setup my Az DevOps pipeline to live in a different branch?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm setting up Azure DevOps pipeline for CI for a .NET Core 3.0 mvc project.

I've created a new branch, `DEVOPS`, that I would like to store the YAML file in.  The file includes a trigger for changes to the `master` branch:

> trigger:
>   - master
>
> pool:
>     vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
>
> # other steps/tasks below...

I deleted all files except `.gitignore` and `azure-pipelines.yml` from the `DEVOPS` branch, committed it, and pushed it to origin (Az DevOps Repo).

I then switched to the `master` branch, deleted the `azure-pipelines.yml` file, committed, and pushed.

***this did not trigger the pipeline***

Then I made a change to one of the views in master, committed, and pushed.

***this also did not trigger the pipeline***

So, how can I configure Azure DevOps Pipelines to store the `azure-pipelines.yml` file in a branch other than `master`, and trigger on changes to `master`?

Comment: It seems that you cannot trigger a build against a branch where yml file doesnot exist.

Comment: Hi, how’s the things going? What about the below explanation and the method? Feel free to leave comment if you still has puzzle or any issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your operation steps and the YAML configuration, the build could not be triggered is reasonable.

Let's focus on the YAML configuration first. In you YAML definition, you set `master` as trigger branch. This means only changes occurred on `master` can trigger this build pipeline.

In your first action, you delete some files from `DEVOPS` branch. Then commit and push it into `remotes/Origin`. But, as what you defined in pipeline, this action could not trigger this pipeline. This is as expect.

Next, in `master` branch, you delete the `azure-pipelines.yml` file, then commit and push it. Note, at this time, the remote master branch has been sync with the local master branch. In one word, after you push to origin, no `azure-pipelines.yml` file exists in the master branch of Azure Devops.

**BUT**, whether the build can run depends on whether yml exists or not. Yeah, you have made some changes on master branch. But without `yml` file, the build could not be ran successfully. That's why you encountered the pipeline did not be triggered.

And, same reason for your next action.

---

> How can I configure Azure DevOps Pipelines to store the
>   azure-pipelines.yml file in a branch other than master, and trigger on
>   changes to master?

Until now, this could not be achieve if what's your build definition type is **YAML**.

For the pipeline which definition type is YAML, to achieve what you expect, the `yml` file with the same configuration must also stored in the relevant branches which be defined in the pipeline.

Take the example you described in the question. If you only store the `yml` file in `DEVOPS` branch, no matter do any changes on `master` branch, it will never trigger the build.

To achieve trigger on changes to master, this `yml` file must also stored in master branch. So, the pre-condition of build pipeline which definition type is YAML can be triggered is, the yml file must also exists in the relevant branches if it is listed in the yml definition. This because, this build type can run based on the `yml` from source files.

Comment: Then for what purpose is there a branch trigger *that takes a branch name*? It's a bizarre limitation.

Comment: @SamAxe,In fact, it all work fine and simply for classic editor. Just for YAML, since the yml file stored in repository and the the YAML builds based on this yml file, then cause this limitation.

Answer (score 0):

I think I was able to achieve what you're trying to do.  If you set the default branch of the build, that's where it's pulling the yaml file from.  So I clicked on "Triggers" from the top right dropdown.  And then I clicked "YAML", and under that clicked "Get Sources", and then to the right, switched branches by clicking "Default branch for manual and scheduled builds".

Afterwards I checked it by clicking edit on the build pipeline and my branch that was designated for the yaml file was correct, in your case you said DEVOPS.  Then it should still trigger the build by whichever branch you specified in the yaml file.